# How much or many FPS?

Tags: grammar

FPS stands for 'Frames Per Second' it's a measurement used in games and films. Most people would say, "How much FPS do you get?" but expanding this would turn to "How much frames per second do you get" which doesn't make sense and "How many frames per second do you get?" does make perfect sense.

My Question is what's the rule behind many and much and does this term break any of them?

Comment: There was a [similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31719/difference-between-much-many-a-lot-of-and-lots-of) on the English Language Learners site which might be of interest. Another way to ask your FPS question would be "What is your frame rate?"

Comment: Along WV's lines, it would never occur to me to ask either *how much* or *how many* unless saying *frames per second*; I would ask *what FPS do you get* as with MPG, APR, or ROI.

Comment: Can you back up the claim that “most people would say” it that way? From personal experience, I don’t believe I’ve ever heard _anyone_ say it that way, though I have heard people say things like, “How many FPS is that?”. But more commonly still, as others have mentioned, _frame rate_ is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question on our English Language Learners site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31719/difference-between-much-many-a-lot-of-and-lots-of) gives the general rule on use of 'much' or 'many', which is that countable quantities use 'many' while uncountable quantities use 'much'.

There is an additional point, not discussed in that answer, which is that *units of measurement* are always considered to be countable, even if they can be fractional. So you say:

> How many miles away is the destination?

even if the answer might be 0.5.

Frames per second is a unit of measurement, so it takes 'many'.

Comment: I was thinking about money. It is countable but we still ask "How much money do you have?"

Comment: @WeatherVane No, the noun _money_ is not countable in the normal sense. It is only countable in the specialised sense ‘sum of money’ (where it has the plural _monies_). Money isn’t a unit of measurement, either – that would be, for example, ‘dollars’, ‘quid’, ‘rand’, ‘bob’, etc. Using miles as in this answer: ‘miles’ is to ‘dollars’ as ‘money’ is to **‘distance’** – not the unit of measurement, but the thing the unit measures. (Interestingly, a lot of currency measurers have no distinct plural form, but that’s just an incidental aside, not directly relevant here.)

Comment: This is good in terms of answering *much* versus *many*. But I don't think anybody really says either. *FPS* is commonly used as a noun. They would say *my FPS is*, *I get x FPS*, or *What is your FPS?*

Comment: @JasonBassford So your point is that I am answering the question.

Comment: No, that you've answered it incompletely. *Many* works fine with *frames per second* but not very idiomatically with *FPS*. The question itself is based on a false premise.